# Which Xamarin version do I have installed in Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin

I have used the self-contained installer for Xamarin for Windows [here](http://xamarin.com/download), but I have an issue that requires that I know the specific version of Xamarin that's installed. How do I find this information? (Note that I'm looking for the version of Visual Studio plug-ins, **not** Xamarin Studio).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the version of your Xamarin plug-ins for Visual Studio by going to "Help" -> "About Microsoft Visual Studio" in VS, and scrolling down to the Xamarin plug-ins.

Note that Xamarin consists of many different software packages that don't follow the same version numbering: The main Visual Studio plug-in, a plug-in for Android development and a plug-in for iOS development. In addition, there's Xamarin Studio and the individual API/SDK packages required for Android/iOS development.

In case it's relevant for you, Xamarin has a detailed guide for where to find various logs and debug information that's relevant to Xamarin development. You can find this at

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-

The URL above is obsoleted. New link is at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs

Comment: I have Xamarin version 16.4. According to the official blog, there is only version 4.x, not 16.x. What went wrong here? I have VS 2019.

Comment: @ygoe I currently have various 16.6 modules installed in VS, according to this technique. My projects have Xamarin **Forms** 4.7 installed as a NuGet package - is this the discrepancy?

Comment: These does not show the versions for packages like Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials, and to get these can refer to the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using VS 2019, go to Tools | Nuget Package Manager | Manage Nuget Packages for Solutions | Click Installed Tab and there you will find your Xamarin.Forms by Microsoft version details. In my case as I post this answer current stable is 5.0.0.2012

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can check in Nuget Solutions Package Manager.

Everytime when you start a new project, Its advised to update Xamarin to the latest version. Have fun..